# PHP Socket Server Loses Connection to MySQL Overnight

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a PHP socket server that sits around waiting for connections, then talks to a database to resolve them. It works fine when I'm testing, but then when I leave it sitting around, the next morning it no longer talks to the database.

When I look at my logs, I see this:

```
200327 11:54:37    24 Connect   dbuser@localhost as anonymous on dbname
       24 Quit
```

Where I'm expecting to see something more like this:

```
200327 11:54:20    23 Connect   dbuser@localhost as anonymous on dbname
           23 Query SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE num=4
           23 Query SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE num='4' AND info='deleted'
           23 Query SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE num='4'
           23 Quit
```

But for some reason, after the server has been running for a while, the queries never go through after that initial connection.

The only thing I can think of is that maybe my PDO object is somehow timing out, as I create it once when I fire up the server.

```
$dbh = new PDO($dbName,$dbUser,$dbPass);
```

Any thoughts on what might be going on, and if creating the PDO object at the start of the process isn't correct, how to better manage that resource?

PHP is PHP 7.0.33, MySQL is 10.1.44-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 Debian 9.11.

Comment: have you got any error/debug logging in there which might help you understand what the code actually does?

Comment: this might be related to wait_timeout variable of mysql server which is default 8 hours
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout

Comment: ADyson: Some. I can see that the socket server receives the connection, and then it runs the command that should generate those first two MySQL connections. It then returns the result  that either says "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE num=4" returned nothing or that the MySQL function didn't return. It's obviously the latter as that data is in the table.

Comment: Markownikow: Thanks, that sounds very likely it's it, as no one but me is using this test server right now. I'd be happy to accept that as an answer, especially if you have any suggestions on best practices for writing a server that may or may not get connections over any eight hour period.

Comment: Shannon A.: Thank you, I posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql server will close inactive connection after "wait_timout" seconds. The variable is described here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout

I would suggest to open new connection on client side(php) every time request comes to socket and close after job is done because increasing wait_timeout could lead to too many hanging connections(unless php server never goes down and reuses same db connection)

Comment: For anyone looking at this in the future, this was the right answer.

I took the `new PDO` creation out of the server startup, and instead create it every time I take a new command, and `unset` the handle after the command is parsed, and now I no longer have a problem with the database handle disappearing.